# How to activate/deactive a dynamically resized element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to dynamically resize an element upon clicking and have the ability to revert back to its original size upon a second click. I thought `toggleClass` could do the job, but apparently it didn't:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(this).click(function() {
  var new_size = // dynamically calculated value;
  $('.resize').css({'width': new_size, 'height': new_size});
  $(this).toggleClass('resize');
 });
});
```

Is there an easy way to work around this?

Comment: `toggleClass` is the easy way for this.

Comment: if toggleclass not working is likely your css rule for that class is not specific enough

Comment: @charlietfl: how do I make it more specific?

Comment: depends on other rules that apply to that eleemnt...have to look in a browser console to see what rules apply, and make yours more specific...this may help  http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
$('.resize').css({'width': new_size, 'height': new_size});
```

isn't doing what you think it is.  For your object to change size when you add a class, you need an actual CSS rule that specified the `.resize` class which won't work with a dynamically calculated size.

This line of code is just setting a height and width on any object with the `.resize` class and isn't doing anything to objects without that class.  Thus, you could resize the object once (when it had the class) and never change it's size again.  It won't toggle anything.

What I would suggest is that you save the old size and then you can restore it when you want to and also save the toggle value.  jQuery's .data() functions work well for saving this type of info:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var this$ = $(this);
        // if it's currently at the dynamic size, restore the original size
        if (this$.data("dynamicallySized")) {
            $(this.css(this$.data("origSize"))
               .data("dynamicallySized", false);   // set flag that we're not dynamic
        } else {
            // save original size
            this$.data("origSize", {height: this$.height(), width: this$.width()})
              .css(new_size)
              .data(dynamicallySized", true);    // set flag that we're dynamically sized
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I find your solution more versatile, eventually pick yours over solarise's, though it is harder to digest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery.data() to store the old values, ready to reapply on the next click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(this).click(function() {
  if($(this).data("old")){
    var old = $(this).data("old");
    $(this).css({'width': old, 'height': old});
    //clear out the old_size data so it won't execute this next time
    $(this).removeData("old");
  } else {
    var old = $(this).height();
    var new_size = // dynamically calculated value
    $(this).data("old", old);
    $(this).css({'width': new_size, 'height': new_size});    
  }
 });
});
```